# Controled number scale mapping

Tags: javascript, three.js, physics

I need to map a rotation angle scale in degrees to a light intensity scale (a rotating sun) that goes from 0.0 to 0.9.  This is the mapping function I'm using:

```
function map (num, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max)
{
    return (num - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min;
}

//(degree, degree in min, degree in max, light intensity out min, light intensity out max
var fade = map(30, 180, 360, 0.0, 0.9);
```

However, the fade in and out is too slow leaving only a small amount of time when the light intensity is at it's max.  I need more control over how the scale mapping is done - how do I achieve this?

Comment: Depends on what curve the mapping should have. How about applying `Math.pow(result, x)` to the result of `map()` where x is smaller than 1. The smaller x is, the earlier the intensity raches its max.

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to extend the function and keep it flexible so I can adjust but I ultimately need a rapid fade in, a long period of being at the max and finally a rapid fade out.

Comment: ah, ok, so a fade out aswell. Your code doesnt do a fade out. Let me try to elaborate in an answer.

Comment: @WestLangley, while I appreciate you taking the time to look at and edit my question it's unclear why you keep removing the three.js tag.  The question may not specifically be about three.js (general javascript), however, I do mention lights and am using floating numbers that are fairly particular to three.js.  In a javascript only context this might not make sense to anyone who attempts to answer - the three.js tag provides context that may help communicate what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @garrettlynch I guess we will have to agree to disagree, then. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said already you can achieve a initial rapid change and a long period of low change with `Math.pow(x,<1)`.

To have it fade in and then fade out again, you can scale the value by 2 and subtract what's above 1 with the value.

```
function map(num, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max, factor)
{
  var delta = Math.max(0,num-in_min)
  var scale = delta/(in_max-in_min)

  return Math.pow(Math.min(1,scale*2)-Math.max(0,scale*2-1),factor)
}
```

When `factor` is 1 it's linear. When it's smaller than 1 it's polynomial.

See illustration:

```js
function map(num, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max, factor)
{
  var delta = Math.max(0,num-in_min)
  var scale = delta/(in_max-in_min)
  
  return Math.pow(Math.min(1,scale*2)-Math.max(0,scale*2-1),factor)
}



// UI

var degrees_slider = document.getElementById('degrees')
var factor_slider = document.getElementById('factor')
var degrees_disp = document.getElementById('degrees_disp')
var factor_disp = document.getElementById('factor_disp')
var intensity_disp = document.getElementById('intensity_disp')

degrees_slider.oninput = factor_slider.oninput = update

function update(){
  var num = degrees_slider.value
  var fact = factor_slider.value
  
  degrees_disp.innerHTML = num
  factor_disp.innerHTML = fact
  intensity_disp.innerHTML = toPercent(map(num, 180, 360, 0.0, 0.9, fact))
  
}

function toPercent(val){
  return Math.round(val*100)+'%'
}

update()
```

```css
#intensity_disp{
  font-size: 32pt;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<label for="degrees">Degrees</label>
<br>
<input type="range" id="degrees" min="0" max="360" step="1"/>
<span id="degrees_disp"></span>

<br><br>

<label for="degrees">Linearity</label>
<br>
<input type="range" id="factor" min="0" max="1" step="0.01"/>
<span id="factor_disp"></span>

<div id="intensity_disp"></div>
```

Comment: Many thanks this worked with some tweeking to suit my needs, marked as correct.  I posted my modified version below.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @Manuel Otto above is correct if you need a scale that runs up from a number to a higher number (and that's what I asked for).  However, I needed more flexibility as I'm adjusting my sun position adhoc at the moment while testing and my final function below accommodates running from a number to a lower number as well (since it's degrees it gets reset at 360 to 0) - so for example 180 -> 60 (180 to 360 and then 0 to 60 = 240 degrees):

```
//input degree, minimum degree possible, maximum degree possible, scale minimum, scale maximum, speed of scale fades (0.0 - 1.0 = fast to slow) 
function map(num, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max, factor)
{
    //if input degree is greater than minimum degree possible
    if (num >= in_min)
    {
        //simple subtraction
        var delta = Math.max(0, num - in_min);
    } else {
        //subtract from 360 and add the input degree
        var delta = Math.max(0, ((360 - in_min) + num));
    }

    //if the maximum degree possible is greater than the minimum degree possible
    if (in_max >= in_min)
    {
        //simple subtraction
        var scale = delta / (in_max - in_min);
    } else {
        //subtract from 360 and add the maximum degree possible
        var scale = delta / ((360 - in_min) + in_max);
    }

    return Math.pow(Math.min(1, scale * 2) - Math.max(0, scale * 2 - 1), factor);
}
```

Posting it here in case it's useful to anybody else.